# CSV MNIST data set: ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 28, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, keras, classification, mnist

I want to classify the MINST data set (csv) with keras. This is my code but after running it I got this error. Do you know how can I solve it **ValueError**: **Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 28, 10) are incompatible**

```py
from keras import models 
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as  tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import to_categorical, plot_model
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
#Load dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='sigmoid',input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_split=.3)

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['training', 'validation'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Here I got error from the code. I know it is cause because of input shape but I do not know how should define that. x_train.shape is (60000, 28, 28) and y_train.shape is (60000, 10)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-7c9220a71c0e> in <module>
      1 model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 2 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_split=.3)
      3 
      4 plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
      5 plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    503     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    506             *args, **kwds))
    507 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2655     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   2656     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 2657         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   2658             self._name,
   2659             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

th
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 28, 10) are incompatible
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: which line makes problem? Did you use `print()` to check what you have in variables? And what shapes do you have in variables?

Comment: Add a Flatten layer just before the dense layers.

Comment: Your edit did not improve the question at all. Again, please provide the **full traceback** from the error.

Comment: in model. fit() . I know this error happens because of input_shape but I do not know how to declare that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dense layers, are not able to handle 2D data like images, you should first flatten input to a vector, then pass it to your model, otherwise, you will get the other dimensions in the output, and then your labels and logits (model output) are not compatible and you will get error.

Add a flatten layer to your model like this:

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]))) #add this
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Thank you Kaveh, your answer solved my problem

Comment: @ Kaveh I did but it seems my reputation is not enough to cast a vote.